# How can a voltage follower's output have any current through it?

Tags: operational-amplifier

> Voltage follower circuit is used to create isolation between two different kind of circuits. Due to high input impedance,, so the input current is much lower than the output current while the output voltage follows the input voltage. So the voltage follower provides large power gain across its output. Due to this behavior, Voltage follower used as a buffer circuit and can be used to isolate stages while building multistage filters or some other multistage circuit.

This quote is from [this webpage.](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/voltage-follower-circuit-using-op-amp)

I think I understand clearly the purpose of a voltage follower circuit, and this quote explains it pretty well.

There is one key aspect that I can't seem to grasp and I can't find the info anywhere:

The part of the circuit which is connected to the output consumes current.

Where is this current coming from? Since the battery is connected to the input of the op amp, it is hi-z and there is no current possibly flowing out of the battery.

How can a current form from the battery to the output stage of the circuit?

To my understanding, the output load would have the battery's voltage, but should not be able to operate because of the high impedance input being the only connected component to the battery.

It doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: Operational amplifier has the power supply line. May be through it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output current is provided by the voltage source, which is connected to the pins 4 and 7 of the op. amp.

Ignoring the negligible input currents, these are the relevant ones:

[image]

Notice that B1 provides current to the potentiometer RV1, which acts like a voltage divider, and B2 provides power to the op. amp. (and its output load).

As noted, this is a real op. amp., so there is negligible currents at the inputs. There are also other non-ideal characteristics, like, e. g., the model in your post is not a rail-to-rail component, so the inputs and the output do not work using the full power source voltage range.

Comment: Maybe you can add a small line addressing this mistake by the OP to further clear his confusion?
'since the battery is connected to the input of the op amp, it is hi-z and there is no current possibly flowing out of the battery'

Comment: Please put a different opamp part number in there, LM324 or something similar designed for single rail operation. Somebody might see this and think it's a good idea to use 741s like this, or in fact 741s at all. This circuit won't behave as 'expected' with <2 V from RV1, and maybe even < 3 V could cause problems.

Comment: It is clear now, thank you! And can I use a voltage follower circuit with the op-amp's power pins disconnected, and that would give me a voltage to read without any current, say for reading an analog sensor with a microcontroller?

Comment: @Neil_UK: An LM709?  >:)

Comment: @JCSB Take a look at the text at the beginning of your question ("power gain"). An op. amp. is an active component and this power gain must come from the power source. It does not work without a power source.

Comment: If you use a voltage follwer configuration without the power pins connected, at best you'll get some approximate facsimilie of the input voltage feeding through to the output, but it could be several diode voltage drops wrong, and you might damage the amplifier.