# Voltage follower output current

Tags: operational-amplifier, unity-gain

We know that voltage follower will have a nonzero output current. How do I solve for this value? Let's say I am using an LM358 op amp to implement the buffer (unloaded), do I just use the [Output Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znxMl.jpg) given in the datasheet? Or do I consider other factors here?

Comment: "*We know that voltage follower will have a nonzero output current.*" I don't know that. Where did you get the idea?

Comment: How do you solve *what* for this value?

Comment: @Transistor I got it from this thread: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/547542/how-can-a-voltage-followers-output-have-any-current-through-it

Comment: "How do I solve for this value?" Use Ohm's law. You know the voltage at the output. If you know the impedance of the circuit it is driving, you can calculate the current.

Comment: I think this is simpler than you are thinking.  The current will be whatever it needs to be to support that voltage.  As is usually the case, the current is dependent on the load at whatever your voltage is.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say I am using an LM358 op amp to implement the buffer (unloaded), do I just use the Output Current given in the datasheet?

If the output is unloaded then the output current will be zero as there is nowhere for it to go. (It's an open-circuit.)

> Or do I consider other factors here?

If there is a load then the output current will be determined by  that load. For a resistive load it's easy: \$ I = \frac V R \$. For a reactive load (inductive or capacitive) it gets a bit more complicated as the voltage and current will not be in phase.